# BottomSHeet not Collapsing when clicking an item on it

Tags: android, onclick, fragment, bottom-sheet

I created a bottomsheet using fragment and Extending BottomSHeetDialogFragment class, Now the problem is when i clicking any of item on bottomsheet then it not collapsing the bottomsheet how can i do that?

this is my BottomSheetFragment Class

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Inflater inflater1 = new Inflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);


        navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view_id);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.all_list_item_id:

                        // Do something and collapse sheet

                        return true;
                    case R.id.add_new_list_item_id:

                        // Do something and collapse sheet

                        return true;
                    case R.id.bottom_sheet_item3_id:

                        // Do something and collapse sheet

                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple just call the method dismiss() from your onclick method.

Reference : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html#dismiss()

the code should like that given below

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private BottomSheetBehavior bottomSheetBehavior;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        Inflater inflater1 = new Inflater();
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bottom_sheet, container, false);


        navigationView = view.findViewById(R.id.navigation_view_id);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.all_list_item_id:
                        dismiss();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.add_new_list_item_id:
                        dismiss();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.bottom_sheet_item3_id:
                        dismiss();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        return false;
                }
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

}
```